# How to increase the height of a github gist on webpage?

Tags: html, css, github, gist

Following other questions on here, I have managed to increase the size of the gist window embedded on my webpage, but the data within the window doesn't increase, as see in the image below. I am using CSS to increase the height:

```
.gist-data {
    height: 800px;
}
```

The below image shows the result of this, where the window height increases but just with white space at the bottom. Does anyone know how I can increase the height of the data within the window as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS:

```
.gist {
   overflow:auto;
}

.gist .blob-wrapper.data {
   max-height:800px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i was having a similar problem. The gist is rendered in a box, percentages doesnt seem to have an affect but changing the viewport height does. Was a bit of trial and error to find the right size.

```
.render-viewer {
  height: 90vh !important;
}
```